# On NServiceBus Profiles

Tags: nservicebus

I've been trying to find out ways to improve our nservicebus code performance. I searched and stumbled on these profiles that you can set upon running/installing the nservicebus host.

Currently we're running the nservicebus host as-is, and I read that by default we are using the "Lite" version of the available profiles. I've also learnt from this link:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles

that there are Integrated and Production profiles. The documentation does not say much - has anyone tried the Production profiles and noticed an improvement in nservicebus performance? Specifically affecting the speed in consuming messages from the queues?

Answer (score 0):

One major difference between the NSB profiles is how they handle storage of subscriptions.

The lite, integration and production profiles allow NSB to configure how reliable it is.  For example, the lite profile uses in-memory subscription storage for all pub/sub registrations.  This is a concern because in order to register a subscriber in the lite profile, the publisher has to already be running (so the publisher can store the subscriber list in memory).  What this means is that if the publisher crashes for any reason (or is taken offline), all the subscription information is lost (until each subscriber is restarted).

So, the lite profile is good if you are running on a developer machine and want to quickly test how your services interact.  However, it is just not suitable to other environments.

The integration profile stores subscription information on a local queue.  This can be good for simple environments (like QA etc.).  However, in a highly distributed environment holding the subscription information in a database is best, hence the production profile.

So, to answer your question, I don't think that by changing profiles you will see a performance gain.  If anything, changing from the lite profile to one of the other profiles is likely to decrease performance (because you incur the cost of accessing queue or database storage).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you tuned the logging yourself, we've seen large improvements based on reduced logging.  The performance from reading off the queues is same all around.  Since the queues are local, you won't gain much from the transport.  I would take a look at tuning your handlers and the underlying infrastructure.  You may want to check out tuning MSMQ and look at the disk you are using etc.  Another spot would be to look at how distributed transactions are working assuming you are using a remote database that requires them.

Another option to increase processing time is to increase the number of threads consuming the queue.  This will require a license.  If a license is not an option you can have multiple instances of a single threaded endpoint running.  This requires you shard your work based on message type or something else.

Continuing up the scale you can then get into using the Distributor to load balance work.  Again this will require a license, but you'll be able to add more nodes as necessary.  All of the opportunities above also apply to this topology.